# Is it correct to say "under the shelter of X, a Y was taking place?"

Tags: word-usage, sentence

Is it correct to say the following?

> All that could be heard was the wind blowing, and giant waves
>   crashing against the rocks in the beach. **Under the shelter of
>   the inn, a barbecue was taking place.**

Meaning that some people are having a barbecue right in front (or behind) of the inn. And this is partially protecting them from the wind.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with this sentence? To me, here "under" implies "beneath". I would use a different preposition.

Comment: @Peter Shor So what preposition would you use?

Comment: I would use "in".

Comment: @PeterShor: or rather I would recommend _placing_ the BBQ somewhere other than under the inn; that's doesn't seem safe or practical. Grammatically all is fine: "Under the shelter of the trees, a druid seance was taking place."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Under the shelter of [something]", is probably the more correct choice when the shelter is provided by something concrete, as in your question.

"Under shelter of" (without the 'the') is perhaps used with more abstract objects ("under shelter of the night", "under shelter of confidentiality").

Both seem to be widely used to mean "sheltered by".

"In the shelter of the inn" would, in my view, imply being inside the inn.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But why do I have to remove the *the*?

Comment: The more I think about, the more complicated it gets. I have edited the answer to reflect the conclusion I've reached so far. Let's wait and see what SE says...

Comment: Thanks! Ha, I don't know what to think anymore.